# Implementing an event inherited from an interface

Tags: c#, .net, events, inheritance, interface

In my project, I need to implement an event that fires when a popup or something similar is pulled up so that I can close anything that needs to hide behind it for whatever reason.

For context, I have 3 files in play here, `MainShell` which fires the event, `IShell` which is an interface that `MainShell` implements and defines the event, and `Reports` which listens for the event.  I could have put the event in `MainShell` and made everything simpler, however the project references would become circular if I did that.  That's just what I have to work with.  I can, however, refer to the `IShell` interface that defines the functions `MainShell` uses.  Unfortunately, it seems attempting to use an event from a derived class/interface causes the implementation to become very complicated and picky for some reason.

In my interface file:

```
public class ModuleShownEventArgs : EventArgs { }    

public delegate void ModuleShownEventHandler(object sender, ModuleShownEventArgs e);

public interface IShell {
        event ModuleShownEventHandler ModuleShown;
        ... }
```

In my listening class:

```
public Reports() {
    ...
    Container.Shell.ModuleShown += Shell_ModuleShown;
    ... }

private void Shell_ModuleShown(object sender, ModuleShownEventArgs e) {}
```

In my event firing class:

```
event ModuleShownEventHandler IShell.ModuleShown
{
    add
    {
        ((IShell)this).ModuleShown += value;
    }
    remove
    {
        ((IShell)this).ModuleShown -= value;
    }
}

public void OnModuleShown()
{
    ModuleShownEventHandler handler = ((IShell)this).ModuleShown;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, new ModuleShownEventArgs());
}
```

I've managed to stop most of the compiler's complaints, but I'm down to one problem: there's an error where I assign `handler = ModuleShown`,

> the event 'IShell.ModuleShown' can only appear on the left hand side
>   of += or -=

This prevents me from easily comparing my event to `null` for checking, and prevents me from firing my event at all.

**Questions**

How can I get this to work?  Why can't I fire my event?  Why does defining events change so drastically when they come from a base class/interface?  Keep in mind that this project is quite large and I've only started working on it recently, so I can't make sweeping structural changes to it.

I am using Visual Studio 2013, and my project's .NET Framework version is 4.0.

Comment: Have you tried the same thing, but without implementing IShell explicitly (you don't show your full class declaration, but it appears to me that IShell must be implemented explicitly)? That handler assignment (among other things, as you mention in a comment below) can only be performed in a method of the class that defines the event property; perhaps that required cast to IShell violates that rule.

Comment: No problem, happy I could help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you are using explicit interface implementation. You should be using implicit instead.

```
    public class Shell : IShell
    {
        public event ModuleShownEventHandler ModuleShown;

        public void OnModuleShown()
        {
            ModuleShownEventHandler handler = ModuleShown;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new ModuleShownEventArgs());
            }
        }
    }
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx

Ideally you will be passing around the instance that implements IShell as the interface if your concern was to hide the event from the Shell implementation.  Typically, you use explicit interface implementations when you do not want your class to publicly expose an interface specific member.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I definitely tried this earlier before I started messing with all the explicit implementation stuff, but this time it worked.  I guess earlier I hadn't noticed that my errors weren't updating reliably without me attempting to build the project.  Thank you!

Comment: Now I have to deal with a new problem, that the popup that gets called after the event fires animates onto the screen, and for some reason the iframe I am hiding waits until that animation is finished before it goes away...

Comment: @DanielStone Putting on my psychic debugging hat, I'm guessing it's all happening on one thread? But yeah -- new question.

Comment: Yeah I know, just trying to take a crack at it myself first.

Comment: If anybody wanted to help with my new problem, [I've posted it here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33659444/2988943).  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

It should look something like this instead.

```
public void OnModuleShown()
{
    if (((IShell)this).ModuleShown != null);
        (((IShell)this).ModuleShown)(this, new ModuleShownEventArgs());
}
```

Comment: I've already tried that, the other line produces the same error.