# UI function firing before quick event finishes

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, silverlight, events

I have a web browser frame docked in a Silverlight application, and sometimes full-window XAML/Silverlight UI elements can pop up over it.  The old problem, which I've more-or-less fixed, is that the web frame's contents didn't seem to play nice with the Silverlight content, always wanting to be rendered on top.  This isn't really an issue now since I have an event that fires whenever an application-obscuring popup appears, but now there's a new problem.

My code that launches pop-ups looks like this:

```
public void OnModuleShown()
{
     if (ModuleShown != null)
         ModuleShown(this, new ModuleShownEventArgs());
}

public void ShowModule (string uri, string headerTitle, string message, string transition = "DefaultTransition")
{
    // Security and destination validation

    GetInfoFromURI(uri, out contentKey, out dataKey, out securityToken);

    OnModuleShown();

    ShowLoadingSpinner();

    _loadModule(contentKey, dataKey, securityToken, headerTitle, message, transition);
}
```

My code that handles the event looks like this:

```
private void Shell_ModuleShown(object sender, ModuleShownEventArgs e)
{
    if (browserFrame.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
    {
        browserFrame.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        return;
    }
}
```

The new problem is that even though I call the event before I start loading and displaying the new module, and even though all the event is doing is changing a web frame's visibility, the module tends to appear first if the loading time is short.  Since the module's appearance is animated, it looks even worse since the web frame seems to be waiting for the module to finish its animation before it vanishes.

**Questions**

Is there some kind of threading method I can use to address this?  I really don't want to use `Thread.Sleep` but it's the only one I know of that would fix this without large program changes I can't make.  Even better would be if there was a way to get this web frame to play along with Z-indexes or something similar.

I am using Visual Studio 2013, and my project's .NET Framework version is 4.0.

Comment: I've been playing around with `Thread.Sleep`, and it doesn't seem to really do anything besides cause a delay no matter where I put it.

Comment: I think that this may happen is because events in Silverlight are asynchronious, so the handling code is being executed in other context. May be you can create a `Task` with `ContinueWith` option, or, if your project can't use it because of .NET version, you can investigate similar libraries from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18403822/213550).

Comment: @VMAtm - Yeah, it's something like that.  I've noticed that other web frame based controls in other parts of the app also seem to have similar problems, so it's kind of a result of dealing with a program where different parts render by whole different sets of rules.  I've tried a whole bunch of threading stuff (`ContinueWith`, `RunSynchronously`, using `Dispatcher` to try and keep both processes on the UI thread, etc) and no luck.  At least I can live with it not looking good as long as it's functional.

Comment: May be you can try something silimar to tunneled events from WPF? Like to send some `callback` object from your eventhandler?

Comment: It'd have to be a callback of some kind, but I'm not sure if it'd work since my event handling class can't actually refer to the class firing the event due to circular references.  It can only subscribe to the event at all because the event is part of an interface the firing class inherits.

Comment: Such event can be done via IoC Containers.